# Closed form posterior for a mixtures of two univariate Gaussians

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, conjugate-prior

Giving a univariate Gaussian mixture model $$\pi_1N(x|\mu_1,\sigma_1)+(1-\pi_1)N(x|\mu_2,\sigma_2),$$ are there any priors for $\pi_1$, $\mu_1$, $\sigma_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma_2$ which gives a closed form posterior?

Comment: It depends what you call closed form. A conjugate prior gives a closed form posterior mixture but with $2^n$ terms (Dielbolt & Robert, 1994).

Comment: $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of observed independent random variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ as stated in https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345907, am I right?

Comment: $n$ is the sample size.